# String to function javascript

Tags: javascript

Say i am using some of the html5 data chars and i want to know what function to call when say something is completed for a certain div tag.

so my data would look like

```
data-callback='jsAPI.aSubset.desiredFunction'
```

How would i convert that callback (a string) into the function that i want to call.  A simple global function such as

```
data-callback='_myfunction'

<script>
    function _myfunction() { alert("yes my function"); }
    $("div").click(function() {
        var fn = $(this).data("callback");
        if (typeof fn === 'function') {
            fn();
        }
    })
</script>
```

but how do i do it with the previous one `jsAPI.aSubset.desiredFunction`  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using square brackets only works if you have no `.` chain.

Try this instead:

```
var elms = fn.split(".");
var curr = window;
var nxt;
while(nxt = elms.shift()) curr = curr[nxt];
curr();
```

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a great use case for the dreaded `eval()`.

I would do something like:

```
var fnString = "jsAPI.aSubset.desiredFunction";
var fn = eval(fnString);
if (typeof(fn) === "function") {
    fn.apply();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use square brackets...

```
jsAPI.aSubset[fn]();
```

so...

```
if (typeof jsAPI.aSubset[fn] === 'function') {
    jsAPI.aSubset[fn]();
}
```

Comment: I said the item was a string...  Your just calling the function in the string as if i can magically just know what to call.

Comment: I should clarify that all you need/want in the `data-callback` attribute is the actual function name `desiredFunction`. If you can't know the object nesting beforehand, then you'd want something like [@Kolink's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8918903/1106925).

Comment: @Michael: Why would it be magic to know beforehand which subset will be used?

Comment: yes i know.  I wont know the object nesting before hand.  Else i would of done the solution i provided for in my question (which is what you did).

Comment: @Michael: The solution provided in the question wouldn't work at all, because `fn` would be a string.

Comment: @AdamRackis: Thanks bro. Gotta admit I was more focused on the text at the bottom that looked more like object reference than a string. Not really sure why one would take this approach in the first place, but there must be some good reason I guess.

Comment: If I had to store crap like that, I'd prolly just eval it all - rather than loop through the string split cobbling an object together.  But I'm evil like that...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to just use `Function("functionstring")`. The Function function returns a function from a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try `window[fn]()` if the function is defined in the global scope.